# PHP empty function in python

Tags: php, python

I have the following PHP code, and for the life of me I can't think of a simple & elegant way to implement around the empty() function in python to check if the index is defined in a list.

```
$counter = 0;
$a = array();
for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
  $i = ($i > 4) ? 0 : $i;
  if empty($a[$i]){
    $a[$i]=array();
  }
  $a[$i][] = $counter;
  $counter++;
}
```

if I do

```
if a[i] is None
```

then I get index out of range. However I am aware of ways to do it in multiple steps, but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473099/python-how-to-check-if-a-given-index-in-a-dict-exists-yet

Comment: Must it be implemented with an array? A `dict` would let you use `a.setdefault([])` and be done with it...

Comment: the exception you get is exactly the way to go by enclosing it in a `try...catch` block. If you could show us your python code so far it may be even easier to help you out and probably find an easier way to implement your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP Arrays and Python lists are not equivalent. PHP Arrays are actually [associative containers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
>   different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
>   table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more.

In Python, the map data structure is defined as a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping):

> A mapping object maps hashable values to arbitrary objects. Mappings
>   are mutable objects. There is currently only one standard mapping
>   type, the dictionary.

The `empty()` function [serve many purposes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). In your use context, it is equivalent to the Python `in` operator:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a[1] = "x"
>>> a[3] = "y"
>>> a[5] = "z"
>>> i = 3
>>> i in a
True
>>> i = 2
>>> i in a
False
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event you were trying to do it with a list, you would have to actually set that index to none, otherwise the element wouldn't be there you'd possibly be trying to check an index past the end of the list.

```
>>> i = [None]
>>> i
[None]
>>> i = [None, None]
>>> i
[None, None]
>>> i[1] is None
True
```

Comment: Hi thanks, if I initialize it to none then I might as well initialize them properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
# variable may not exsists    
if (variable in vars() or variable in globals()) and variable != "" and variable == False:
    pass
```